# Google not showing image link

Tags: google-chrome

When I am searching 'medieval engineers' in google page its not showing Image link.

Please see the below screen shot however it works for other keywords.
can anyone help me for the same as I need to call the images by Java API.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search this in images.google.com
 : https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1368&bih=675&q=medieval+engineers&oq=medieval+engineers&gs_l=img.3...364.364.0.1062.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.msedr...0...1ac.1.64.img..0.0.0.tDkHIj8QKgk